# Trello API: vote on a card

Tags: trello

Is it possible to vote on a public card with Trello's REST API?

The documentation is not very helpful:

https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html

https://trello.com/docs/api/action/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The route you're looking for is [POST /1/cards/(card id or shortlink)/membersVoted](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-membersvoted).  The only valid value for `value` is your own member id.

In general, the best way to figure out things like this is to do the action in the web app, and watch the Network tab in your browser's dev tools to see what request it makes.